# Sending JSON object with int array to java REST AngularJS

Tags: java, javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I have a problem with sending my JSON object via angularjs' $http.put method.

When I used to send JSON containing only String there was no problem, but now I want to send ints and one int array and I can't get them matched(java class that is going to be mapped with JSON).

```
    $scope.edit = function(game, goalScorersHome, goalScorersAway) {
  var JSONScore = {
    'id' : game.id,
    'idHome' : game.homeId,
    'idAway' : game.awayId,
    'goalsHome' : game.goalsHome,
    'goalsAway' : game.goalsAway,
    'goalScorers' : []
  };

  for(i=0;i < goalScorersHome.length; i++) {
    JSONScore.goalScorers.push(goalScorersHome[i].id);
  }

  for(i=0;i < goalScorersAway.length; i++) {
    JSONScore.goalScorers.push(goalScorersAway[i].id);
  }

  $log.log(JSONScore);

  fixturesService.editScore(game.id, game.homeId, game.awayId, JSONScore);
```

This is where I send my JSON. 'Goalscorers' has to be long[] type.
And on the REST Server I have class(Score.java) with

```
  private int id;
  private int goalsHome;
  private int goalsAway;
  private int idHome;
  private int idAway;
  private long[] goalScorersId;
```

So when I send it I have this message given:  PUT http://localhost:9000/push-server/rest/season/1/1/2 500 (Internal Server Error)angular.js:8495 (anonymous function). I'm only asking for help how to map this JSON object(JSONScore to java class. When I pass Strings it works!! This is how this JSON looks like [JSONScore image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZDsI.jpg)

Comment: this problem:org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "
goalScorers" (Class pl.bpl.push.server.json.Score), not marked as ignorable| at
[Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@6b01fc0f; line: 1, column: 74] (through reference cha
in: pl.bpl.push.server.json.Score["goalScorers"])

Comment: ok, goalScorers vs GoalScorersId... No question. I don't know how to delete.